# NoMethod Error in Offers#show

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a rails application for products and it's offers. I have created a products page through which products can be created.This page is working fine. But when I try to create the offer page for the corresponding product and I redirect it to the list page it gives me 'NoMethodError in Offers#show
Showing /Users/smita/workspace/products/app/views/offers/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `offer_name' for nil:NilClass'

I'm using rails 4,ruby 2.2.3 and mysql database

Here is my code:

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index     
      @product = Product.all
  end

  def list
      @products = Product.order("products.product_name ASC")
  end

  def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
      @product = Product.new
  end

    def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
        @product = Product.new(products_params)
    # Save the object
        if @product.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
        redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

    def delete
        @product = Product.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :action => 'list', notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    private
    def products_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :product_desc, :product_image, :product_rate)
  end 
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers
end
```

CreateProducts

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
        t.string "product_name"
        t.string "product_desc"
        t.string "product_image"
        t.integer "product_rate"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

products/list.html.erb

```
<div>
  <h2>Products</h2>

    <%= link_to("Add New Product", {:action => 'new'}) %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Id</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Desc</th>
      <th>Product Image</th>
      <th>Product Rate</th>
    </tr>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= product.id %></td>
      <td><%= product.product_name %></td>
      <td><%= product.product_desc%></td>
      <td><%= product.product_image%></td>
      <td><%= product.product_rate %></td>
      <td>
          <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => product.id}) %>
          <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => product.id}) %>
          <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => product.id}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this entry ?' }) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

products/new.html.erb

```
<div>
  <h2>Create Product</h2>

    <%= form_for Product.new ,:url => {:action => :create, :controller => :products} do |f| %>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:product_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Desc</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:product_desc) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Image</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:product_image) %></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Product Rate</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:product_rate) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <%= submit_tag("Save Product") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

products/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}) %>

<div>
  <h2>Show Product</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
        <td><%= @product.product_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Desc</th>
      <td><%= @product.product_desc %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Image</th>
        <td><%= @product.product_image %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Rate</th>
        <td><%= @product.product_rate%></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

offers_controller.rb

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
   def index 
       @offer = Offer.all   
   end
  def list
      @offers = Offer.order("offers.offer_name ASC")
  end

  def show
      @offer = Offer.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def new
      @offer = Offer.new
  end

    def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
        @offer = Offer.new(offers_params)
    # Save the object
        if @offer.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
            redirect_to(:action => 'list', notice: 'offer was successfully created.' )
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

    def delete
        @offer = Offer.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :action => 'list', notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    private
    def offers_params
        params.require(:offer).permit(:product_id, :offer_name, :offer_start_date, :offer_end_date, :offer_description)
  end 
end
```

offer.rb

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :offers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :offers
end
```

CreateOffers

```
class CreateOffers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :offers do |t|
        t.string "product_id"
        t.string "offer_name"
        t.string "offer_start_date"
        t.string "offer_end_date"
        t.string "offer_description"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

offer/list.html.erb

```
<div>
  <h2>Offers !!!</h2>

    <%= link_to("Add new offers", {:action => 'new'}) %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Id</th>
      <th>Offer Id</th>
      <th>Offer Name</th>
      <th>Offer start date</th>
      <th>Offer start date</th>
      <th>Offer description</th>
    </tr>
      <% @offers.each do |offer| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= offer.id %></td>
        <td><%= offer.offer_name %></td>
        <td><%= offer.offer_start_date %></td>
        <td><%= offer.offer_end_date %></td>
        <td><%= offer.offer_description %></td>
      <td>
          <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => offer.id}) %>
          <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => offer.id}) %>
          <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => offer.id}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this entry ?' }) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

offer/new.html.erb

```
<div>
  <h2>New Offers</h2>

    <%= form_for Offer.new ,:url => {:action => :create, :controller => :offers} do |f| %>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Offer Name</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:offer_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Offer start date</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:offer_start_date) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Offer end date</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:offer_end_date) %></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Offer description</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:offer_description) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <%= submit_tag("Save offer") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

offer/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}) %>

<div>
  <h2>Show offers</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Offer Name</th>
        <td><%= @offer.offer_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Offer start date</th>
        <td><%= @offer.offer_start_date %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Offer end date</th>
        <td><%= @offer.offer_end_date %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Offer description</th>
        <td><%= @offer.offer_description %></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should only include the relevant code. You should not expect those who are willing to help to sift through your entire app. In this case everything except  OffersController and `offers/show.html.erb` is irrelevant.

Comment: Your models are wrong, you should have `belongs_to :product` in your Offer class (`offer.rb`), and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :offers` should go in your `Product` class (`product.rb`).

Answer (score 1):

You should change your setup so that you get an *index* of offers when you click on a product. You can do it with [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products do
   resources :offers, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create] #-> url.com/products/:product_id/offers
end
```

This will allow you to "scope" the offers flow around which `product` you're looking at:

```
#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
class OffersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_product

   def index
      @offers = @product.offers
   end

   def show
      @offer = @product.offers.find params[:id]
   end

   private

   def set_product
      @product = Product.find params[:product_id]
   end
end
```

This will have to be combined with the appropriate [model associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :offers
end

#app/models/offer.rb
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end
```

From the looks of your tables, you'll need to make sure you have the appropriate `foreign_key` for your `offers` (`product_id` in the `offers` table):

[image]

--

This will give you the ability to access `url.com/products/1/offers` to get all the offers for that product, and then click through to `url.com/products/1/offers/5` to see that specific offer.

---

In regards your error,

> no method 'offer_name'

... you need to read up on how attributes work in Rails.

Each time you call an instance variable, you're using the following:

```
@product.product_name
@product.product_desc
```

These are **wrong**.

You need to reference the various *attributes* for each of the objects. Attributes are basically the database column names, which you have before you prepended the object name for some reason.

To get rid of the error, you basically need to *only* reference the attribute name itself:

```
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= offer.id %></td>
        <td><%= offer.name %></td>
        <td><%= offer.start_date %></td>
        <td><%= offer.end_date %></td>
        <td><%= offer.description %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```